# Appveyor Xamarin: Components cause CI server to fail

Tags: c#, xamarin, continuous-integration, components, appveyor

I added a component to my xamarin android project.
Now when my project runs in appveyor it fails with this point:

```
$zipPath = "$($env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER)\xpkg.zip"
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://components.xamarin.com/submit/xpkg', $zipPath)
7z x $zipPath | Out-Null
Command exited with code 2
```

it build and runs fine on my environment. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit Code 2:

```
Unrecognized command.
```

It is not finding the `7z` command for your unzip/extract step.

Try `get-7zip.ps1` if you already do not have it:

---

```
Write-Host "Installing 7-Zip ..."
$instPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
if (!(Test-Path $instPath))
{
    Write-Host "Determining download URL ..."
    $web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $page = $web.DownloadString("http://www.7-zip.org/download.html")

    $64bit = ''

    if ($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -match '64')
    {
        $64bit = 'x64'
    }

    $pattern = "(http://.*?${64bit}\.msi)"
    $url = $page | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches -First 1 | foreach { $_.Value }

    $file = "$env:TEMP\7z.msi"
    if (Test-Path $file)
    {    
        rm $file | Out-Null
    }

    Write-Host "Downloading $url -> $file"

    $web.DownloadFile($url, $file)

    Write-Host "Installing..."
    Write-Host "(Note: please approve the User Account Control (UAC) popup if necessary...)"

    $cmd = "$file /passive"

    Invoke-Expression $cmd | Out-Null

    while (!(Test-Path $instPath))
    {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }

    Write-Host "Done!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "7-Zip already installed."
}
```

---

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dougthor42/wafer_map/478faec644c06887d2cf6823457ac8e63a47ce77/appveyor/get-7zip.ps1

Comment: but i thought z7 was supposed to be preinstalled in appveyor environments?

Comment: It is installed and included in the path within a "Build Worker" environment, but we have had a problems and just installed it ourselves. You can try `z7` all by itself on a build script line to see if it is being found

Comment: This is a stupid question probably but how do I run the script on appveyor I cant seem to make it run...?

Comment: I keep getting this:
.\get-7zip.ps1 : The term '.\get-7zip.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\get-7zip.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\get-7zip.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: the rest:
Command executed with exception: The term '.\get-7zip.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Seen it is not finding the script in the current dir `Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included`, are you including the powershell script within your repo that you are pushing to Appveyor? Is it in the current directory since you are specifying `.\xxxxx`

Comment: Oh hey actually this was not the problem for me, The problem was with the component libraries in my project. They werent added properly for some reason so I had to go into the xamarin component store and just click "add to project" again and now it all works good! :)